# echo link on mysql variable depending on

Tags: php, html, mysql

showList.php

```
<?php

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['title']; 
    echo $row['author'];
  }

?>
```

So basically this is a book search sorted by genre, which will show a list of books matching the desired genre.

What I want from there, is that e.g. the title or a button is clickable to reach viewBook.php, which in turn shows the specific book the user has chosen.

I've figured that I should somehow fit $_POST/$_GET in there like on the page previous to showList.php to be able to pick ut up on viewFilm.php, but I haven't manage to pull it off. Combining PHP and HTML is proving harder than I'd have thought, never dealt with a webbased language before and not two simultaneously either.

Any help/tips/links to guides is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: I would look into AJAX, it's meant for doing things like this. Although if you want to not use AJAX you could probably get around it by loading all the information at the start and hiding it. Then have a button toggle that information. With a lot of data the site load may be noticeable in that case.

Comment: no, I think Nathalie asked not about ajax solution, but the logic how web application works (she is so far from ajax for now :-) )  @NathlieZ24 does your code work? does this php code really outputs list of books now? if yes, I can help you to go forward step by step

Comment: @KimAlexander Not sure I can explain it in proper terms..

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I'll look in to AJAX anyway, not sure I really like php!

Comment: @KimAlexander Why does enter submit my comments? <sigh>
So. Pick genre via a POST method button.
POST value received on next page, filling variable $genre.
Variable used in MySQL-query.
{Fetch results via while-loop (mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)), filling $row.
Print results with MySQL data.} code above ^

That's the process, and it works. EDIT: shift-enter didn't give me a new row either.. <sigh>

Comment: what do you mean by "not sure" when question was : "does it work"? do you see any book title and author on the page? (yes or no?  ;-) 'not sure' is not acceptable :-))

Comment: @KimAlexander Thought you wanted me to explain the process. My bad. Did it anyway. It works!

Comment: would you prefer to chat in skype? or here?

Comment: @KimAlexander People asleep around me right now, I'd prefer it here now or Skype another day (unless I can manage to have it working myself, of course).

Comment: @KimAlexander 
It can't be that complicated though can it? Feels like I should somehow be using the same process as previously, with $_POST that is

Comment: check my answer. you are very welcome if any questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $str = '<a  href="viewBook.php?book_id='.$row['id'].'">';
    $str .= $row['title'].' ('.$row['author'].')';
    $str .= '</a><br />';
    echo $str;
  }
```

on your viewBook.php script you can get book_id from $_GET

or if you have no book_id in your $row:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $str = '<a  href="viewBook.php?book_title='.$row['title'].'">';
        $str .= $row['title'].' ('.$row['author'].')';
        $str .= '</a><br />';
        echo $str;
      }
```

:-)

hope it is helpful for you

Comment: Thanks, makes perfect sense. Though, do I use $_GET to pick up 'id' on the following page? Like $book = $_GET['id']?

Comment: yes, not $_GET['id'] but  $_GET['book_id']. where book_id is any parameter var name you want and placed after ? (question mark) in url. You can send more than 1 parameters using ampersand sign:
viewBook.php?book_id=1&book_title=bible&author=unknown 
:-)

Comment: Right then, got it working (kinda!)! Thank you so much, sat for like 20 mins wondering why printf made it look weird lol. I'd +rep you 100 times, or at least once, if I could :&